# take screen shot of a specific area in sikuli for eclipse gui

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I am trying to take screen shot of my screen while running the test execution.
I use the below code using sikuli java:

```
 Screen screen = new Screen();
 ImageIO.write(screen.capture().getImage(), "png", new File(file-location+"1.png"));
```

Another way i am using is java awt:

```
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(screenSize);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage image5 = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image5, "png", new File(AppConstant.IMAGE_DIR+"1.png"));
```

But the problem is, it is taking screen shot of my whole screen with Ubuntu menu bar. What I want is to take only the screen shot of my eclipse window, a specific region.

Comment: You will need to find the size and location of the eclipse window, or whatever you are trying to screenshot, and then take a screen shot with the Robot class using those dimensions.

Comment: soemthing like : BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture( new Rectangle(x, y, width, height) );?????

Comment: or in which way i can only get the screen size of my eclipse window size?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Sikuli App Class](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/). For eg. If the app is on focus while running the test, you can use the below method:

```
Region appRegion = App.focusedWindow();
Screen screen = new Screen();
 ImageIO.write(screen.capture(appRegion).getImage(), "png", new File(file-location+"1.png"));
```

This way only the app window is captured as per your requirement and since you have a region now, you can manipulate it to increase/decrease the size captured.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is through using the `App` class. So if you start your Eclipse process like this:

```
// You might need to provide full path here
App app = App.open("eclipse.exe");
```

Then you can use the `capture` method with `app` region as argument. The `app` region can be obtained through `window()` method. So:

```
App app = App.open("eclipse.exe");
ImageIO.write(screen.capture(app.window()).getImage(), "png", new File("1.png"));
```

Comment: no, my application is not opened like this. My application is eclipse based application which i open using sh script while running my testing.